# Haskell - cannot run simple prgram

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to run a simple Haskell program.

Here is the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = T.putStrLn "someFunc1"

lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String
lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"

let a = lucky 7

putStrLn a
```

When I attempt to compile the program using: `stack build`

The error is :

```
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
   |
16 | putStrLn a
   | ^
```

I'm following the guide at http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters but it is all based on using REPL, whereas I want to produce reproducible results in the IDE. I'm using the Haskell IDE for IntelliJ and created the project using `stack new first-project` following guide from https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/ .

How to compile and run this Haskell program ?

Update :

Using the suggested answer from pedrofurla the modified code is :

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Lib
    ( someFunc
    ) where

import qualified Data.Text.IO as T

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = T.putStrLn "someFunc1"

lucky :: (Integral a) => a -> String
lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!"

a = lucky 7

main = putStrLn a
```

The code now compiles ( using `stack build` ) .

On running the code ( using `stack exec first-project-exe`
)it just outputs "someFunc1" . I expect "LUCKY NUMBER SEVEN!" to also be printed to screen as function `a` is called by main :

```
main = putStrLn a
```

Have I missed a step ?

Comment: Try adding main to the module declaration, `module Lib (someFunc, main) where`.

Comment: What is in the stack configuration files you made for `first-project-exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `let` keyword and add a *main* function it will work:

```
a = lucky 7

main = putStrLn a
```

`let`s are expressions that should be used in body of functions. An Haskell program requires an entry point, that's what the *main* function is.